# Use jQuery Text Complete with a array with Key and Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm using the [jQuery.textcomplete](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/) plugin with the following code:

```
$('#textarea3').textcomplete([
    { // html
        mentions: {
            'test': 'test@gmail.com', 
            'othertest': 'othertest@gmail.com'
        },
        match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
        search: function (term, callback) {
            callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
                return mention.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
            }));
        },
        index: 1,
        replace: function (mention) {
            return '@' + mention + ' ';
        }
    }
]);
```

I want to when the user type *@te* show the options but show only the `mention.[value]` and I wan't to return the `replace: function` like

```
replace: function (mention) {
    return '@' + mention.[key] + ' ';
}
```

So, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert that mentions dict into an array and you can do it.

```
var mentions = {
  'test': 'test@gmail.com', 
  'othertest': 'othertest@gmail.com'
};

var arrayOfMentions = Object.keys(mentions).map(function(key) {
  var val = {};
  val[key] = mentions[key];
  return val;
});

$('textarea').textcomplete([
  {
    mentions: arrayOfMentions,
    match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
      callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
        var value = mention[Object.keys(mention)[0]];
        return value.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
      }));
    },
    template: function (mention) {
      return mention[Object.keys(mention)[0]];
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (mention) {
      var key = Object.keys(mention)[0];
      return '@' + key + ' ';
    }
  }
]);
```

See jsbin at http://jsbin.com/farewa/edit?js,output

Comment: The link above references a broken textcomplete link. 
 Here is an updated bin: http://jsbin.com/hedexuxupe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Something like this... I'm working on a fiddle...

```
        callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
            for (property in this.mentions) {
                  return mention.indexOf(property) === 0 ? mention : null;
            }

        }));
```

Comment: did the other guys answer work for you?   If not, I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

I've a situation inverted than one: I need to search in `keys`, but replacing with `value`:

```
$('#maintext').textcomplete([{
  mentions: arrayOfMentions,
  match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.mentions, function(mention) {
      var key = Object.keys(mention)[0];
      return key.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
    }));
  },
  template: function(mention) {
    return '@' + Object.keys(mention)[0];
  },
  index: 1,
  replace: function(mention) {
    var key = Object.keys(mention)[0];
    if(mention[key]){
        return mention[key];
    } else {
        return '@' + key + ' ';
    }
  }
}]);
```

See Here: https://jsfiddle.net/FabioBeneditto/od5jumvh/